# How do I create a symbolic branch in Git that points to current iteration branch?

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration

For Continuous Integration purposes, I want to have a special "symbolic" branch in Git that I update periodically to point to the Git branch for my team's current iteration. We name our iteration branches like `sprint-1`, `sprint-2`, et cetera, and we want our CI system to run a build whenever a commit is pushed to the current iteration branch.

I know I can create a "symbolic ref" by doing `git update-ref current-sprint sprint-5`, but the CI tools I use seem to be unaware of my creation of this symbolic ref.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you have your CI system build a commit to *any* branch?  (In CircleCI, that's just a regex - not sure about other CI systems.)

Comment: Also FWIW, the one-branch-per-sprint model seems somewhat superfluous - an alternative model is to just use `develop`, and then tag once a sprint is complete.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I probably should have said continuous deployment. We don't need commits to feature branches released anywhere. Good idea re: `develop` branch and tagging.

Answer (score 0):

We use Team City and it works well for us, but we don't create sprint specific branches, but we have a main `dev` branch that we use to create feature branches and then merge those back to `dev` once the feature is done.

Then Team City builds the `dev` branch when it picks up the change.